# Can employees be asked to pay back company money lost to a scam?

Tags: united-states, law, fraud

Our shift leader received a call from someone who she thought was from Corporate. She was told that money was missing from our store and a federal investigation was going on. She was asked to send a team member with all the cash in the store to a certain location to protect it from being stolen.

The team member left with the money, and did not return for over an hour. We did not have her number in our scheduling app, we couldn't find an emergency contact list and the GM wasn't answering his phone. The team member eventually reached out to us and told us that she was told to buy a bunch of prepaid cards, hand over the numbers vocally, then rip up the cards and spread them in a dumpster. By this time, the police were involved and we told them the situation.

Our GM now says that from his perspective, the shift leader took the money out of the safe and it was never seen again. He says that if she quits her job, he will keep her paycheck and file a police report against her. Her other option is to continue working at the store until all the money is paid back.

Should the shift leader be accountable for losing company money to a scam? Can the employer ask her to pay back the money?

Comment: I suggest you get legal counseling

Comment: You are asking for determinations which vary significantly from jurisdiction to jurisdiction. In order for people to be able to reasonably answer, you need to provide the country/state about which you are asking.

Comment: If you want to know the legal situation then you better post the country where this is happening and which law applies.

Comment: It seems your shift leader did not follow some procedures. I guess there would be i.e. a rule that in case of any unusual event she should contact XYZ. Maybe that is a written rule, maybe it was told her. How did she verify that the caller is allowed to give her instructions? (i.e. look up a name, call a known number, etc.)? If she didn't verify this why did she follow the instructions of someone she does not know (legally speaking)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I think this is trolling.

Comment: @Paparazzi: I understand people could be in a situation like this and they want a fast answer without consulting an expensive lawyer. Even if the post is trolling (I don't think so) it could be still interesting for other people to learn from this. Unfortunately lots of scammers are out there ...

Comment: I’m sorry for being unclear. We are in Arizona, in the United States. And yes it was kind of obviously a scam, but they are both very new. These girls are still in high school, and it was the team members first day. The team member ripping up the cards... nobody had any idea about until after we finally got ahold of her.

Comment: @Edgar If it is trolling then OK.  I am only one vote.

Comment: I don't think this is trolling at all. This kind of scam happens in Taiwan everyday. To the OP, the team member bought the prepaid cards. The shift leader should ask her for receipts which can be the evidence to prove that it was a scam.

Comment: This kind of scam is very common is Taiwan. I am afraid the variation is spread to other countries. [Los Angels Times](http://www.latimes.com/world/asia/la-fg-china-taiwan-fraud-20160427-story.html) **:** _Fraud in Taiwan took off around 2001. In one scam, criminals posing as government workers would call random numbers and claim that the victim's national health insurance files had been stolen. They would ask the victim to place their bank savings in a "safe" account, purportedly run by the government, to help solve the case._

Comment: A better title probably would have been useful. It raises some interesting points, like is the employee responsible and can the store dock her pay.

Comment: Trolling or not, it's off topic because the core questions being asked concern *the legality* of the situation and the involved parties' *legal options.*  We aren't equipped to properly answer this on Workplace.SE, regardless of whether it's a real situation or not.

Comment: The underage girl needs to document everything. Take pictures/video of her surroundings, training manual, etc. Along with a parent, she needs to go to the police station, file a police report on the scam (if one hasn't already been made) and include the threats from her GM. Then she needs to quit her job, file for unemployment, and file a claim with the department of labor in her State. Any follow-up police interview after that, the parent will need to be careful, act as a go-between, and/or hire an attorney. A naive girl like that can be easily pressured into making a false confession.

Comment: But otherwise, assuming this is in the US, I wouldn't anticipate any problem or followups from the police. The GM can not press charges. That's at the discretion of the District Attorney. If anything, the only person who's acting illegally and like a bully right now is the GM. If I were her parent and if she's underage, after she quits, I would demand that the GM stopped all contacts with my daughter and have all the communications be in writing and be addressed to me instead.

Comment: I've heard of people being fired for this sort of thing, and it's pretty normal in this sort of case for the police to consider the employee a prime suspect.  But the GM seems to be acting pretty shady.  He's basically saying "pay me the money and I won't call the cops."

Answer (score 1):

Let me get this straight

- Corporate called late last night.  Why was corporate working late at
  night and just discovered the theft.
- A federal investigation (that came to culmination late at night)?  Why did federal agents not come to the scene.
- Shift manager did not verify the call was from corporate.
- Assigned the transfer to a team member you did not have a phone
  number for.
- Told to up rip up the cards and put them in a dumpster.
- Shift manager has access to the safe. If someone was stealing the money
  she is a suspect so why would they call her.
- The police are already involved. No purpose to GM filing a police report
  against her.

I think this is trolling.  Not even good trolling.

Assume it is not trolling. Supervisor is an obsolete idiot to believe this and not check out the story. Does it rise to criminally negligent - I doubt it. I agree with a comment that an employer cannot withhold pay without a judicial order at least in the US. IANAL (I Am Not A Lawyer)

Comment: The way I read it, corporate didn't call; a scammer pretending to be corporate called, lied about a federal investigation, and told an employee to buy, transfer, & destroy a bunch of prepaid credit cards — or are you just criticizing the shift leader for not putting 2 and 2 together fast enough?

Comment: The former of what you said is correct, it was a scammer. I agree that our staff were very unintelligent. But they were not prepared to handle a situation like this on their own, being new and young. Our GM is telling the shift lead if she quite, he will keep her paycheck and file a police report. If she stays, he will take the money out of her paycheck until it is repaid. Is this legal? And if he files a police report, will they make the shift lead pay it back? Despite our GM not posting her contact I do, having no emergency contact sheet, and not answering for hours on end?

Comment: @jwodder No kidding it was not really a call from corporate.

Comment: It is almost certainly illegal to dock the employee's wages for losses due to theft. Contacting an attorneyight be wise.

Comment: @GlenPierce: Was it theft? Or was it negligence or something like that? As hard as it is I imagine the best the employee can do is try to get a deal in which the money is deducted over time or something like that. Few people would want to employ someone with that record - especially if the police and maybe justice system gets involved.

Comment: Let me be more clear: It is illegal to confiscate money from employees' paychecks without a judicial order in the United States. A high school student falling for a scam is not guilty of a crime, they are a victim of one.

Comment: @jwodder Not clear what point you are trying to make there. You are essentially repeating what paparazzi said in his answer. If you are just agreeing with his answer "in other words", it's fine, but from the overall tone of your comment, it sounds like you disagree with him, which confuses me.

Comment: @Paparazzi, This is a common scam, even in the US. And yes, high school kids on the job are especially vulnerable to it. Take a look at this extreme example for instance. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UFXeXK3szOk The fact is. Many of our kids act like sheep. We need to teach them how to be assertive and question authority. And these types of places, fast food joints, or other establishments, love to recruit the type of kids that don't talk back and do what they're told. But if you don't train them, don't supervise them, and give them a key to the safe, what happens is on you, not the kids.